# Illegal String Offset using Foreach on CodIgniter using sqlsrv_query external database

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I am trying to get the employee list from a external sql database i already know hot to get this using a regular php page but i am new with codeigniter and i want to try if this could work.

So my controller.php looks like this.

```
class Patients extends CI_Controller {

        function index() {

            $data['title'] = 'Patients';

            $data['patients'] = $this->Patients_model->get_patients();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('patients/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');                  

            print_r($data);     

        }
```

I put the `print_r($data)` to see if it outputs correctly and i did get the array data below, but its weird since its only returning a single data since my sqlsrv_query declares top 30, anyways.

```
Array ( [title] => Patients [patients] => Array ( [employee_i] => 3321 [first_name] => Zyriel [last_name] => Tanawan [labor_clas] => SD [current_de] => WORKSHOP - L.A [date_emplo] => 2016-04-06 00:00:00 [pay_code] => 06 [cost_cente] => 7723 [file_statu] => EMPLOYEE [middle_nam] => Martinez [vacation_l] => 11.0000 [sick_leave] => 0.0000 [line_code] => Facilities Workshop - Laguna [gender] => M [approver_1] => 950812 [approver_2] => 220364 [approver_3] => 940016 [leave_as_o] => 2017-05-19 00:00:00 [section_ma] => [rest_day1] => Sun [rest_day2] => [Current_po] => Machinist [Station] => Laguna ) )
```

And this is my model.php looks like.

```
class Patients_model extends CI_Model
    {
         public function get_patients(){


                $serverName = "MYSERVERNAME"; //serverName\instanceName
                $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MYDATABASE", "UID"=>"USERID", "PWD"=>'MYPASSWORD');
                $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
                if( $conn === false ) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }

                $sql = "SELECT top 30 * from empmas ORDER BY first_name DESC";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
                if( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }


                return sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); 


         }  

}
```

Now on my view.php

```
<?php foreach ($patients as $rows) :?>

            <p><?php echo $rows['employee_i'];?></p><br/>

          <?php endforeach;?>
```

But i get the error below

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'employee_i'

I already tried some answers from other similar questions but it seems different when you are using `sqlsrv_query` any advice would help! thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `$patients`? Is it `$data` or `$data['patients']`? Also `sqlsrv_fetch_array` will fetch the next row, not all of the rows, so that is probably why you are only getting one row of results.

Answer (score 0):

there is error in your code, Please check below. You have to use `$rows` instead of `$value`

```
<p><?php echo $rows['employee_i'];?></p><br/>
```

Comment: Already corrected and updated my question but still `Illegal string offset error`

Comment: Please add this lines. `if ( !defined( 'SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC' ) )
  define( 'SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC', 2 );` before  `return sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: done what you suggested still illegal string offset.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlsrv_fetch_array` returns a single row, so if you use it inside `foreach`, you're looping through *columns*, not rows.

Swapping the return statement in `get_patients()` with the following will solve the problem:

```
$rows = [];
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
return $rows;
```